# Set varibale inside AJAX success is not working

Tags: php, reactjs, symfony

I'm working with React JS and symfony 4, i need to do a insert but i need a token inside the form to send it to the controller, then i get the token by ajax but i need a way that set varible, to set this token but set varible inside ajax is not working because when i send the form the variable (or the state) is empty. so how i can do it ? or if you know other way than you

PD: I speak spanish and i'm learning english so please forgive if i have some mistake, thank you

constructor:

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        token:''
    }
 }
```

ajax:

```
   success: function(response) {

     if (response) {
         this.setState({ token: response })
     }

   },
```

another way

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.token = '';
}
```

ajax:

```
    success: function(response) {

     if (response) {
         this.token = response;
     }

    },
```

Comment: Bind internal function to class. `function(){}.bind(this)`

Comment: forgive me i'm starting with react js, can you explain me what is bind about and how i can do it, i really appreciate it, thank you

Comment: Check the docs. https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html?no-cache=1

Comment: thank you, already works